# Can I restrospectively add a message to a git merge

Tags: git, merge

I just did a branch merge on git, to update my (allegedly) frozen branch of a specific code run. Because I am an idiot, I forgot to add '-m message' on the cmd line (so used to git commit prompting). i.e. I did:

```
git checkout frozenBranch
git merge liveBranch
```

And of course this now means that the last commit message for 'frozenBranch' is the latest 'liveBranch' commit message; whereas what I really wanted was the last commit for 'frozenBranch' to read something like "merged to the livebranch on 2019Feb8; this is the version used to propduce the V2.1 data release"

Is there a way to retroactively add a log message to a merge? I can see how to edit a message for a normal commit, not for a merge.

If not I guess I can check out frozenBranch, make some trivial change, commit and re-merge, but this is a little inelegant!

Answer (score 1):

You can modify your last commit message (merge or not) with

```
git commit --amend -m "New message"
```

If you didn't push yet, perfect, you're set. If you did, you'll have to force push to update the old ref (check with your coworkers).

Comment: I have pushed but I'm the only person on this repo so that's OK

Comment: Nice, so you'll be able to `git push -f origin HEAD` without breaking someone else's workflow :-)

Comment: BUT - since the merge basically just fastfowarded the 'frozenBranch' won't an ammend affect the commit message on both branches?

Comment: @PhilEvans: if there was no actual merge, just a fast-forward, then the two branch names actually point to the same underlying commit. Since `git commit --amend` *doesn't* actually *change* a commit, after amending, you'll have one last commit on `frozenBranch` that's *different* from the last commit on `liveBranch`, but storing the same source. This is probably not what you want. To get what you do want, you need a real merge—a separate commit, with its own separate log message.

Comment: -1 maybe I'm being overly harsh, but amending the last commit of a fast-forward feels importantly bad to me: 1) a non-merge commit's message should describe what that commit changed, and 2) a proper merge commit refers to the two merge "parents" in Git's native "language"/encoding (the commit metadata, which all Git tools/libraries/websites can be expected to understand).

Answer (score 1):

The best way I've got so far is to

1. reset the branch back to the commit before the merge,

   ```bash
   $ git reset --hard "${commit_before_merge}"
   ```

   then
2. merge again, this time with fast-forward turned off:

   ```bash
   $ git merge --no-ff "${branch_you_merged_from)"
   ```

One cool bonus is that this *just adds* a merge commit to the history, it doesn't replace any commits, so you don't have to force push and no one else has to deal with you breaking pulls for them.

### Example

So let's say you just merged branch `live-branch` into `frozen-branch`, and it was a fast forward of four (4) commits. Then you can type:

```bash
# Take your current branch four commits back:
$ git reset --hard HEAD~4

# Merge again, this time forcing a merge commit:
$ git merge --no-ff live-branch
```

### Tips and Tricks

You can use `git log` to find the commit you fast-forwarded from, and either grab the hash or count how many commits ago it was.

Or, if you still have the output from the `git merge` command that did the fast-forward, it currently starts like this:

```bash
$ git merge live-branch
Updating 0850cf3..491e984
Fast-forward
```

and conveniently, that first abbreviated commit hash is the starting commit that you want to reset to:

```bash
$ git reset --hard 0850cf3
```

If you already deleted the branch you merged from, you can just re-create it from the merged-into branch first:

```bash
git branch --delete live-branch  # oops

# no worries, since the merge was a fast-forward, you can
# remake the branch and it has exactly the same history:
git branch live-branch

# now do the steps described earlier:
git checkout HEAD~4
git merge --no-ff live-branch
```

If you deleted the branch locally but not remotely, you can also just recreate it like this:

```bash
git branch live-branch origin/live-branch
```

(this example assumes you're using the defaults of having the remote repository named `origin` and of the branch having same name remotely as locally).

If you *just* did the merge (more precisely, if it was the last Git operation that changed what commit your branch head is on), you don't need to count/remember the number of commits you merged - you can just use `HEAD@{1}` to refer to the commit you were on before the fast-forward:

```bash
git checkout HEAD@{1}
git merge --no-ff live-branch
```

More generally, just as you can use use `~NUMBER` to go back `NUMBER` commits in the *commit* history, you can use `@{NUMBER}` to go back `NUMBER` commits in *your "movements" through the commit history*.

So you can use `git reflog` to find the right movement to go back to. For example, if you just finished working in `live-branch`, switched to `frozen-branch`, merged `live-branch`, switched to `another-branch`, realized you accidentally fast-forwarded and wanted to add that merge commit, and went back to `frozen-branch`, your reflog might start something like this:

```
491e984 (HEAD -> frozen-branch, live-branch) HEAD@{0}: checkout: moving from another-branch to main
00ae7c3 (another-branch, origin/another-branch) HEAD@{1}: checkout: moving from main to another-branch
491e984 (HEAD -> frozen-branch, live-branch) HEAD@{2}: merge live-branch: Fast-forward
0850cf3 HEAD@{3}: checkout: moving from live-branch to frozen-branch
491e984 (HEAD -> frozen-branch, live-branch) HEAD@{4} commit: Add epic live-branch feature
d2ffe45 HEAD@{4} commit: Fix bug in live-branch
```

So in our example, you would look for the line that's right before (under) `merge live-branch: Fast-forward`, because that's the commit you were on before the fast-forward
merge happened - in this case, that's the `HEAD@{3}: checkout: moving from live-branch to frozen-branch` line, so you could use `HEA@{3}`. Once you're comfortable reading the reflog, it sometimes ends up being faster and easier than trying to count the merged commits or find the right commit hash.

Of course, if you didn't already push the fast-forwarded merge to `frozen-branch`, resetting is even easier:

```bash
git reset --hard origin/frozen-branch
```

(this example assumes you're using the default of having the remote repository named `origin`).